# How to divide two columns of type `pandas.core.series.Series`?

Tags: python, pandas, ipython

I need to divide two series element wise. 
The elements are of type float.

```
A = [10,20,30]
B = [2,5,5]
result = A/B
```

I expect

```
result = [5,4,6]
```

but get

```
result = [NaN, NaN, NaN]
```

Comment: Can you show the exact input/output? What you show are no serieses but lists, for which the division not even works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This just works with **pandas** Series as expected:

```
In [3]: import pandas as pd

In [4]: A = pd.Series([10,20,30])

In [5]: B = pd.Series([2,5,5])

In [6]: A/B
Out[6]:
0    5
1    4
2    6
dtype: float64
```

Comment: Ok I guess there are some Zero values inside B and I only saw that part, where I got NaN.

Comment: Also in that case you shouldn't get ``NaN`` but `inf`. But if you have more problems with it, you should show some real code.

Comment: interesting. Even `0/0` evaluates to `inf` and not to `nan`

Comment: If you use floating point numbers, you recover the expected behavior from IEEE-754, `0./0.=nan` and `5./0.=inf`.